# Hide/show element after delay using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have sample text element on view. How can I hide them for example after delay of 3 seconds?
Usage of setTimeout() doesn't work.

Here is my view code.

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"     xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        controllerName="setvisible.Index" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Title">
        <content>
            <Text id="sampleText" text="Test" visible="true"/>
            <Button id="hide" text="Hide" press="hide"/>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

And this is my controller code.

```
sap.ui.controller("setvisible.Index", {
hide: function(oEvent) {
    setTimeout(showElem, 3000);
    function showElem() {
         this.byId("sampleText").setVisible(true);
         this.getView();
    }

}
});
```

Error is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

Comment: Looks like in your code `this` refers to `window`. So `window.byId` is `undefined`.

Answer (score -2):

control sap.m.BusyDialog() caused this error , If you use sap.m.Dialog() it will works.